# Mac OSX Deprecated API - FSRef ref;

Tags: c++, macos

I have the following code that compiles on Pre OSX 10.13 machines

```
  FSRef ref;
  OSType folderType = kApplicationSupportFolderType;
  char path_c[PATH_MAX];
  FSFindFolder(kUserDomain, folderType, kCreateFolder, &ref);
  FSRefMakePath( &ref, (UInt8*)&path_c, PATH_MAX);
```

I need this to work on the latest versions. How can I change this? It currently says such an API does not exist

Answer (score 2):

The modern equivalent requires Objective-C(++) or Swift. In Objective-C, it would be:

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager new];
NSURL *url = [fm URLForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                        inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
               appropriateForURL:nil
                          create:YES
                           error:NULL];
char path_c[PATH_MAX];
[url getFileSystemRepresentation:path_c maxLength:sizeof(path_c)];
```

I don't know exactly how you will use `path_c`. If you only need a pointer to a C string for the path and it won't be used after the `url` object has been released, you could use `url.fileSystemRepresentation`, instead. Even better, switch to using APIs that take URLs rather than path strings, where possible.

Comment: I cannot use Objective C++. This is not iOS. This is C++ on Mac OSX 10.14

Comment: It is possible (and actually not that difficult) to call Objective C code from within a C++ program under MacOS/X.